# Jquery click event preventing

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-events

I have a table which is bind with click events for tr and td. Also I have a document click event. I have a filter setup in my page, so if a particular filter is selected I need to prevent click for tr and td and only trigger document click event. I don't have any control over the element click. I have only control in document click (in other words I can't change the implementation code in element click, but I can bind or handle)

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  $("tr").click(function(evt){
    $("#changehtml").html("Changed");
  });

  $("td").click(function(evt){
    var test ="do some operation";

  });

  $(document).click(function(evt){
    evt.stopPropagation();
    evt.preventDefault();
  });
});
```

Is there any way we can prevent element's click event in scope of document?

Answer (score 0):

If you know the filter, you just need to check on that in your click events. If you return false in a click event it wont do anything. So, try this:

```
$('element').on('click', function () {
  if (myfilter...) {
    return false;
  }

  // do some action    
});
```

Comment: This is handling in element click. Element click is not in my control.

Answer (score 0):

You can handle the event in the capturing phase instead of the bubbling. I can't see how jQuery could do that, so using native API:

```
document.getElementById('[some outer element id]').addEventListener(
    'click',
    function(e) {e.stopPropagation();},
    true
);
```

The 3rd parameter = true makes it be triggered in the capturing phase.